# Map stored procedure to entity to update single column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created an entity using view. For updating I am using a stored procedure and mapped it to the entity. My requirement is to update only one column at a time.

When I try to update in unit of work, it is throwing error when I am assigning value to one column.

Comment: **SHOW US SOME CODE!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by removing nullable = false for all columns.